# Normalizing to BCNF and Removing Anomalies

Tags: mysql, entity-relationship, 3nf, bcnf

How can the following database be normalized to satisfy 3NF and BCNF, as I have repeated foreign keys multiple times and the current design is difficult to perform certain queries as it is.

[image: Database]

Thanks.

Comment: Which tables do you think fail to satisfy 3NF?

Comment: Loan as it has multiple dependencies. Maybe I am wrong?

Comment: 3NF has to do with transitive dependencies, not multiple dependencies. What anomalies are you trying to remove?